# Which are the countries which have zero withholding tax on dividends for foreigners?

Tags: taxes, stocks, dividends

I know Singapore is one of them. What are the other countries? I would prefer to invest in these countries.

Comment: How will it lead to huge savings? You'll still pay the taxes at home all the same.

Comment: I see what you mean. I have deleted that paragraph. But let me clarify. It leads to huge savings if your home country does not tax dividends and capital gains. Citizens from Singapore and Switzerland (not sure) have this advantage. For Americans, unfortunately no.

Comment: So what's the point of your question?

Comment: I think I was not clear enough. Maybe that's the reason for the downvote for what I think is a reasonable question. Puzzled about the downvote. I would like to invest in these countries. This is relevant to readers who come from countries which do not tax dividends at home.

Comment: But these readers can just as well invest at home...

Comment: I disagree with that. Foreign stocks can be better than home stocks. Maybe less relevant for Americans who have wide selection of stocks in their home country.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your home country. Each country has different tax treaties with the other countries. For example, if you reside in UK, you can find the treaties in:

http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/cnr/withholding-tax.pdf

Basically you have to find the "withholding tax treaty" that your country have with other countries. Just type that in Google adding your country of residence.

Good luck!